# Descargar Excel con Angular7 de un servicio rest

Tags: html, angular, spring-boot

He desarrollado un servicio rest que devuelve un archivo .xlsx para que lo descargue el frontal con Angular7.

Antaño realizaba esta operación con:

```
<a href="http://10.111.98.50:8081/***"> Descargar
```

Ahora **no puedo seguir haciendo esto** porque necesito implementar unos tokens de seguridad en las peticiones y como no puedo meterle al `"<a>"`  ese token en la cabecera, me salta el 401...

Por eso ahora estoy usando el .subscribe() de Angular para poder añadir el token de seguridad.

El problema es que cuando llega la respuesta parece ser que no lo "parsea" bien.

Código Angular ->

```
public exportToCsv() {
  this.config.getConfiguration().subscribe(
    config => {
      const endPointDownloadCSV = config.endpoints.monitor.downloadExcel;
      this.data.getDataBff(endPointDownloadCSV + '/' + this.operationId).subscribe(
        data => {
          const blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;charset=UTF-8' });
          saveAs(blob, this.operationId + `.xlsx`);

        },
        err => {
          console.log(err); });
        }
      );
```

Error ->

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Edito**: Acabo de ver que nunca llega a entrar en el "data" , se va siempre por el err.
Yo en el servicio devuelvo directamente un archivo.xlsx

**Edito2:**

Ahora estoy intentando este código en el frontal, el resultado es el mismo que sale en el POSTMAN, carácteres raros, pero a la hora de guardar me dice que el archivo está corrupto.

```
console.log('Token: ' + this.data.user.token);
const data = JSON.stringify(false);

const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.withCredentials = true;

xhr.addEventListener('readystatechange', function () {
if (this.readyState === 4) {
const blob = new Blob([this.responseText], {type: 'application/vnd.ms-excel'});
saveAs(blob, `Prueba.xls`);
console.log(this.responseText);
}
});

xhr.open('GET', 'http://10.111.98.50:8081/a');
xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + this.data.user.token);
xhr.setRequestHeader('***', 'OFI');
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

xhr.send(data);
```

Postman ->

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La diferencia es que si con postman uso el guardar y le doy formato .xls va perfecto, pero si lo hago con angular, al abrir el archivo dice que está corrupto.

Comment: Hola, ¿podrías subir el código en texto en vez de imagen? Gracias

Comment: Ya está modificado y he agregado una notación al final.

Answer (score 1):

Me enfrenté a este problema hace apenas días. Posiblemente en tu `Http#get` (o método similar que estés usando) tendrás que especificar que el tipo de respuesta **no es JSON, sino BLOB**.

Mi servicio tiene esta pinta:

```
getFile(endpoint: string) {
    return this.http.get('/path/to/endpoint', {responseType: 'blob'})
{
```

Y en mi componente tengo uso `FileSaver` para descargarlo, aunque se puede hacer con un anchor:

```
import { saveAs } from 'file-saver';

downloadFile() {
    this.fileService.downloadFile(endpoint).subscribe((data) => {
    if (file) {
        saveAs(file, 'filename.csv');
    }
}
```

Si quieres hacerlo con anchor puedes hacer:

```
downloadFile() {
    this.fileService.downloadFile(endpoint).subscribe((data) => {
    if (file) {
        const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(file);
        const anchor = document.createElement('a');
        anchor.download = `filename.csv`;
        anchor.href = url;
        anchor.click();
    }
}
```

Para darle nombre yo usé el header content-disposition, puse el nombre ahí y lo capturé en la petición para mapearlo al .csv.

Comment: Ya he cambiado el return del servicio:  produces = "application/vnd.ms-excel"), y en el postman y el angular reciben una especie de "Caracteres raros" Pero si lo guardo con el postman con extension .xls PERFECTO, pero si lo guardo con el Angular con .xls dice que está corrupto.

Comment: He modificado la entrada por si te ayuda, he usado el código ese de {responseType: 'blob'} pero da un error de parseado al recibir la respuesta el .suscribe();

Comment: creo que le hace faltar cambiar el content-type , si se sabe el archivo usa `application/vnd.ms-excel` si desconoces el formato usa `application/octet-stream`